# How do I declare a dependency that can be fulfilled by one of many differently named packages?

Tags: package, dependencies, raku, software-distribution

In a Raku distribution how do I depend on either `Foo::Bar` or `Foo::Baz` without requiring both?

Comment: The tags I added do not serve the usual primary purpose of tags (to bring a question to attention of those who contribute to answering). I thought they might help bring your Q to the attention of those searching for answers, which I presume is a leading reason you write your Q+As, but would appreciate reading your reaction. For one thing, is [package] inappropriate? Either of the other two? If you would prefer I generally leave your questions unedited, including tags, I'd be fine with that too; please just let me know. TIA for any reply. And of course for zef, and your excellent Q+As.

Comment: I'm using package as a generic, language agnostic term for what a distribution otherwise represents in raku. Theoretically `Foo:from<Perl>`, `Foo:from<Javascript>` are valid dependencies (or even direct installation identities), and in that context 'package' feels like a more accurate description than 'distribution' or 'module'. Regardless; I don't spend much time thinking about my own tags lest I get stuck over analyzing minor details before my inspiration to answer is expired, and have no issues with anyone adding tags they think are appropriate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `"any": [$dependency-spec1, $dependency-spec2]`. This could look like one of the following (depending on if you use a plain string dependency or a hash):

```
"depends" : {
    "runtime" : {
        "any" : [
            "Foo::Bar",
            "Foo::Baz"
        ]
    }
}
```

```
"depends" : {
    "runtime" : {
        "any" : [
            {
                "name" : "Foo::Bar"
            },
            {
                "name" : "Foo::Baz"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This isn't constrained to raku dependencies either. For instance to declare a dependency on either `curl` or `wget` one can do:

```
"depends" : {
    "runtime" : {
        "any" : [
            "curl:from<bin>",
            "wget:from<bin>"
        ]
    }
}
```

which would cause `zef install $whatever` to inform the user of the missing programs if none are found.